# TPL Continuation task: not sure who is the parent task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, continuations

I have troubles with the ContinuationOption.AttachedToParent flag.

This is my pseudo-code:

```
   Task parentTask = Task.Start(() =>   
   { 
        Task childTask = Task.Start(() => doSomething(),
                                    ContinuationOption.AttachedToParent);
        childTask.ContinueWith(() => followingMethod(),  
                                    ContinuationOption.AttachedToParent);
   }
```

I know if "doSomething()" throws and exception childTask fails and parentTask fails too because the 
ContinuationOption.AttachedToParent option.

I would expect the same behaviour if followingMethod() throws an exception, but parentTask state is Completed.

Am I doing it wrong or the "parent" task of the continuation task is not my "parentTask"?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct but I'd guess you're most likely just using the wrong API.

I know it's just pseudo-code, but `Task.Start()` is an instance method, not a static method, so that won't compile the way you've indicated, and we don't know how you're actually starting the tasks, and the details do matter. `TaskFactory.StartNew` will do what you want, but `Task.Run` will not. Try this:

```
Task parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  Task child = Task.Factory.StartNew(
     () => { Console.WriteLine("foo"); },
     TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
  Task continuation = child.ContinueWith(
     (Task prev) => { throw new InvalidOperationException("Test"); },
     TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
});
try
{
  parent.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
  if (ex.Flatten().InnerException is InvalidOperationException)
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("The continuation exception was propagated to parent");
  }
}
```

If you change

```
Task parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(...)
```

to

```
Task parent = Task.Run(...)
```

then you will not get the behavior you want, because `Task.Run` is essentially a wrapper for `TaskFactory.StartNew` that (among other things) specifies `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` so both nested tasks would run detached (with no parents).  I'm guessing that's what your problem was.

Comment: `StartNew` should be used with explicit task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

The parent task in this context is the one you create the child task **inside** as in `Task.Factory.StartNew` inside a `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

> A child task (or nested task) is a System.Threading.Tasks.Task instance that is created in the user delegate of another task, which is known as the parent task. A child task can be either detached or attached. A detached child task is a task that executes independently of its parent. An attached child task is a nested task that is created with the TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent option.

[Attached and Detached Child Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx)

When you register a continuation on a task, that task is the **antecedent** task, not the parent one.
When you call `ContinueWith` you get back a task the represents the continuation. This is the task you need to check for exceptions:

```
var continuation = task.ContinueWith(() => followingMethod());
```

Comment: I know that childTask is antecedent of continuationTask and that is the "chain" I want. What bother me is the fact that if continuationTask fails parentTask doesn't fail (while if childTask fails parent task fails too). Both my second generation tasks should affect my first generation task in the same way when both are marked as Attached.

Comment: @user3798930 Well, the designers of .Net evidently disagree. `childTask` in your case is never a parent. The continuation would be attached to the parent which is `parentTask`.

Comment: I don't think he was ever implying that childTask should be a parent. The continuation task can have both an antecedent (childTask) and a parent (parentTask), and exceptions in an attached child task are propagated back to the parent task regardless of their antecedent.